# Metadata with more than one language

Tags: pdftex, metadata, pdfx, pdf-a, filecontents

I want to use more than one language in the creation of my Metadata. I was looking at the `pdfx` package [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf). And as I understood it, that would be possible. Based on the information in section 2.3, I built the following code.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
    \Title{Document Naam\sep[en-US] Document name}
    \Author{Name 1\sep Name 2}
    \Language{de\sep en-US}
    \Subject{De samenvatting of korte beschrijving.\sep[en-US] The abstract, or short description.}
    \Keywords{trefwoord\sep[en-US] keyword}
\end{filecontents*}
```

This code is inserted before `\documentclass`. The result is as follows,

[image: 2]

*Note that the description contains only the German description. I imagined that where I put a dark square it would be enabled and could change between languages. Was my guess wrong or is there something wrong with my code?* I believe that my idea was wrong, I don't think that where I signaled it means changing languages.

On the keywords, it is appearing `en-US`, I would like it to be showing only `trefwoord` and in advanced it was possible to see the keywords in English.

In the advanced options I have,

[image: 3]

In the title and description the two options are showing only in German. And besides it is showing `[x-default]`, how would I go about showing `de`?

**Note:** I am using `\usepackage[a-2b,mathxmp]{pdfx}[2018/12/22]`.

Comment: An example of what I want can be seen in this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGd2q.png

Answer (score 1):

Some of this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-2b]{pdfx}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.xmpdata}
    \Title{Document Naam\sep[nl]Document Naam\sep[en-US] Document name}
    \Author{Name 1\sep Name 2}
    \Language{nl\sep en-US}
    \Subject{De samenvatting of korte beschrijving.\sep[nl]De samenvatting of korte beschrijving.\sep[en-US] The abstract, or short description.}
    \Keywords{trefwoord\sep[nl]trefwoord\sep[en-US] keyword}
\end{filecontents*}
```

It seems you need to provide a default value for x-default. Also the languages have to be in the list as far as I can tell.

Despite the claim in the documentation, I believe the keywords are not multilingual b/c they are a "bag container"

As for ease of use: I'd suggest to take a look at the package `hyperxmp` - it seems easier to use.

Also - the dropdown you suspected to be for language change are not, I think they are for easy editing and inserting past meta-data. You need to enable editing on your pdf though.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me.
Do you have any idea how to set a value for `x-default`?

Comment: Can you specify for me? If I understand the [XMP standard (Part 1 pg. 23)](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html) correctly then you must specify x-default and it should be the same as the default langauge. 
In case you arr referting to the example above it is just the first text before the first separator, e.g. for `\Subject`it would be: `\Subject{x-default\sep[nl] NL-Text \sep[en-US] en-US Text}` - does that help?

Comment: In fact I would like to know if it is possible instead of appearing `[x-default]`, appear, for example, `[ne]`?
Thus, in the advanced tab, the texts for `[ne]` and `[en-US]` would appear instead of `[x-default]`, `[ne]` and `[en-US]`.

Comment: as far as I can tell from the standard the default field is required, and has to be a duplicate of the default language.